# Parsing messy XML in Python

Tags: python, xml

I'm super new to coding and if someone could help me in figuring out howto parse XML file it would be awesome.
I'm trying to write a python script that would read all notes created in Gnome-Notes and display it in command line. I've got the load notes part, but I can't figure out howto parse the XML so it would display the text part. The sample data looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note version="1" xmlns:link="http://projects.gnome.org/bijiben/link" xmlns:size="http://projects.gnome.org/bijiben/size" xmlns="http://projects.gnome.org/bijiben">
  <title>Testnote</title>
  <text xml:space="preserve"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="Default.css" type="text/css" /><script language="javascript" src="bijiben.js"></script></head><body id="editable" style="color: white;">Some text for the note.</body></html></text>
  <last-change-date>2021-04-01T20:03:08Z</last-change-date>
  <last-metadata-change-date>2021-04-01T20:02:53Z</last-metadata-change-date>
  <create-date>2021-03-29T10:37:14Z</create-date>
  <cursor-position>0</cursor-position>
  <selection-bound-position>0</selection-bound-position>
  <width>0</width>
  <height>0</height>
  <x>0</x>
  <y>0</y>
  <color>rgb(0,0,0)</color>
 <tags/>
  <open-on-startup>False</open-on-startup>
```

And after parsing I should get only the "Some text for the note." part. I've been trying ElementTree for this. While I don't have issues when working with "clean" xml files provided in the sample I can't figure out what to do with this one.

Comment: Can you post the code of what you've tried so far?

Comment: There is nothing "messy" with your XML (once you close the `note` element).  See [@JustinEzequiel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66911240/290085) for a good way to parse it.   Avoid parsing XML with regex -- such solutions are very brittle.

Answer (score 1):

Should be doable using ElementTree

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

data = '''\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note version="1" xmlns:link="http://projects.gnome.org/bijiben/link" xmlns:size="http://projects.gnome.org/bijiben/size" xmlns="http://projects.gnome.org/bijiben">
    <title>Testnote</title>
    <text xml:space="preserve">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="Default.css" type="text/css"/>
                <script language="javascript" src="bijiben.js"/>
            </head>
            <body id="editable" style="color: white;">Some text for the note.</body>
        </html>
    </text>
    <last-change-date>2021-04-01T20:03:08Z</last-change-date>
    <last-metadata-change-date>2021-04-01T20:02:53Z</last-metadata-change-date>
    <create-date>2021-03-29T10:37:14Z</create-date>
    <cursor-position>0</cursor-position>
    <selection-bound-position>0</selection-bound-position>
    <width>0</width>
    <height>0</height>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <color>rgb(0,0,0)</color>
    <tags/>
    <open-on-startup>False</open-on-startup>
</note>
'''

tree = ET.fromstring(data)
nmsp = {
    'xml': 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
}  # NAMESPACE PREFIX ASSIGNMENT

print(tree.find('.//xml:body', namespaces=nmsp).text)
```

Comment: thank you - will give it a shot. I see that I can do much more with .find than I thought.
While I've been tinkering yesterday I've managed to come to acceptable solution with minidom instead of ElementTree, but I'd like to get more familiar with ET :) .

Answer (score -1):

You can use regex to extract the string between the `body` tags:

```regex
<body.*>(.*)</body>
```

The first `.*` matches for any character, zero or more times, to account for any attributes in the body tag.

`(.*)` captures anything between the tags.

```py
import re

with open('file.xml', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()
    x = re.search(r"<body.*>(.*)</body>", data)

    print(x.group(1))
```